# Camera Insurance for a 3 Month Winter Expedition?

Tags: sony-nex, insurance

So, in February, 2015, we [28M/25M] are planning a 2,000km trek through Northern Canada in winter (down to -40C~) for 3 months. The primary purpose of a camera for us is to film a documentary about our experience.

We have been recommended by a pro film making friend to get the Sony Nex VG-30, which, after researching and checking it out in person, we feel is a solid option. However, we have the chance to save around 700€ if we buy second-hand vs. buying new but with warranty which covers any technical damage.

Our question is, do you know of any insurance companies (we are UK and French residents) that can protect our video camera against things like damage from water and extreme temperatures and condensation etc?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.photoguard.co.uk/digital-camera-insurance.asp

Also check your credit card insurance. Some cover this as part of the yearly fees.